# LeanModal Close Button Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, view, popup

Hi I am trying to use the leanModal.js script I havn't any real knowledge of JQuery so I might be leaving something out in my question that might be needed to answer, anyway I have it working that the window pops up when I do

```
$("#new_playlist_add").leanModal({ closeButton: ".modal_close" });
```

I am trying to get it to show a close button like the example on http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/# but I am not sure how should I go about this?

Comment: sorry dude, but you question is not clear enough to me. is it working or not working?

Comment: It works, but I am trying to include the close button like the version on http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/# but it won't work then. If I do   $("#new_playlist_add").leanModal({ top : 200, overlay : 0.4, closeButton: ".modal_close" }); should it include the button?

Comment: No, it looks like you need to include the button yourself within the `#new_playlist_add` element.

Comment: Yeah your right thanks, I thought it might provide one some way itself silly me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add an element with a class of `.modal_close` in your modal.  Then, clicking it will close the modal.

Here is part of the example from their site:

```
<div id="signup" style="display: none; position: fixed; opacity: 1; z-index: 11000; left: 50%; margin-left: -202px; top: 200px;">
  <a class="modal_close" href="#">Close</a>
  <p> Hello world</p>
</div>
```

The key part is that your modal needs to have an element with the same class as you specify when you start the model.  You need this:

```
<a class="modal_close" href="#">Close me!</a>
```

Comment: It is not 'modal_close' it is 'modal-close'

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a link of close button inside the modal.

```
<a href="#" class="modal-close" >Close modal</a>
```

It will close the modal created by `leanModal()` function.